# .NET 7 API catch-all route without breaking static files

Tags: c#, api, .net-7.0, catch-all, staticfilehandler

We are using attribute routing in a .NET 7 API project. In the startup we call `UseStaticFiles()` before calling `MapController()`.  Something like this:

```
app
   .UseDefaultFiles()
   .UseStaticFiles()
   .MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

We are trying to create a catch all route like this:

```
 [Route("/{**catchAll}")]
 CatchNonExistingRoute()
{
 //implementation
}
```

This works. However, the catchAll route is taking precedence over the static files, which we don't want.

Is there any way around this?

I've been playing with the `app.MapFallback` method, but this also doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly calling `UseRouting` after `UseStaticFiles` (AFAIK otherwise it is implicitly called before everything else which makes `CatchNonExistingRoute` to have precedence over everything else):

```cs
app
   .UseDefaultFiles()
   .UseStaticFiles()
   .UseRouting()
   .MapControllers();
```

Comment: Yes this fixes it. I also figured it out myself. Thanks!